# How to trim strings in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
10.123.214.214:445
124.4235.123:443
124.34352.124.1:80
2142354.1341:80
12435.12412:70
```

Is there a way I can print everything before the **:**? I am thinking awk or sed would be the best way, but I am not sure how to come up with the right command

Expected output:

```
10.123.214.214
124.4235.123
124.34352.124.1
2142354.1341
12435.12412
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cut -d: -f1 file
10.123.214.214
124.4235.123
124.34352.124.1
2142354.1341
12435.12412
```

It's the only thing `cut` exists to do - don't take away it's raison d'être :-).

Answer (score 1):

In AWK, as follows:

```
BEGIN { FS=":" } 
{ print $1 }
```

This makes the colon your Field Separator, so the first word ($1) is everything before the first colon on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk proposal.

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' file

10.123.214.214
124.4235.123
124.34352.124.1
2142354.1341
12435.12412
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, this is the sed equivalent to keep the first column of a `:` delimited file:

```
sed 's/:.*//g' file1
```